# Deploying Django to Azure leads to failure without output

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, azure, deployment

I am trying to deploy a Django project for the first time to Azure through Web Deploy in Visual Studio.  My project runs correctly on my local machine, and I got the polls example project running on Azure through Web Deploy already.  It appears that Web Deploy is not able to find the files to push out to the server since the preview shows no files.  I have compared everything I can think of between the working polls example app and my Django project which does not work.  Interestingly, deploying from the app level works in my Django project, but deploying from the project level does not.  I believe that I need to be able to deploy it from the project level to get it working.

```
------ Publish started: Project: projectname, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, based on my understand, I think the project level & app level you said seems to be `Solution` & `project` in VS as below.

[image]

Please view the offical [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx) to know the concepts in VS.

Try to refer to the wiki section [`Publishing to Microsoft Azure`](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Web-Project#publishing-to-microsoft-azure) to know how to deploy a Django webapp into Azure using VS with [PTVS](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS)

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.